# select column with expression in active record

Tags: php, database, yii

How can I implement this select query in yii ActiveRecord

```
select idCustomer0.idCustomer ,
idCustomer0.FirstName ,
idCustomer0.LastName , 
case when idCustomer0.isDeleted = 0 then idCustomer0.CustomerName  
   else Concat(idCustomer0.CustomerName , " - Deleted") 
      end As CustomerName 
from customers idCustomer0
```

my default scope has isDeleted column equal to 0

I'm trying to create a scope for deleted customers, which will be fetched through a relation

my scope code:

```
public function viewDeleted()  
{  
    $alias = $this->getTableAlias(false , false);  
    $column = $this->representingColumn();  

    $allAttributes = $this->getAttributes();  

    unset($allAttributes[$column]);  

    $text = '';  
    foreach($allAttributes as $attr => $val)
    {  
        $text .= $alias . '.' . $attr . ' ,';  
    }  
    $text .= new CDbExpression( 'case when ' . $alias .'.isDeleted = 0 then '. $alias .'.'. $column .'  
                            else Concat('. $alias .'.'. $column .' , \' - Deleted\')  
                        end  As ' . $column);  

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();  
    $criteria->select = $text;  
    $criteria->addCondition($alias.'.isDeleted = 1');  

    $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith( $criteria , 'or');  

    return $this;  
}
```

I use this scope in my other models search method

```
 public function search() {  
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;  
    $criteria->with = array('idCustomer0:viewDeleted');
```

but the result is not showing deleted columns with `-deleted` cancated to them.

how can I get my column in select with custom expression?

Comment: Do you search for something like that?: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/13101-sql-case-syntax-in-yii/

Comment: not quite, I'm trying to fetch through active record and determain a columns value by an expression